# "What memory!" or "What a memory!"?

Tags: word-choice

Even though the second one seems right, is the first one totally wrong? It sounds ok to me. Correct me if I am wrong. Please explain if possible. Thanks. :)

**Context:**

Someone recollects a proverb that he/she read somewhere. I am intending to praise this person. So which usage would be apt for the situation?

Comment: If we place the interrogative mark, the phrase *What memory?* makes more sense. *what* is an interrogative pronoun. The phrase is asking a question about "memory", maybe the speaker is doubting its existence in a person's recollection. More context is needed. With the exclamation mark and the indefinite article *a*, *What **a** memory!* the speaker might be extolling a person's prodigious memory e.g. *"What a memory! He has the memory of an elephant"*

Comment: Related: [**What a weather vs. What weather**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131271/what-a-weather-vs-what-weather)

Comment: Also related: [**“What a beautiful day” or “What the beautiful day”? And “why”?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143555/what-a-beautiful-day-or-what-the-beautiful-day-and-why)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have added the context. Please check.

Comment: My natural instinct would lead me to choose the second.Effectively you are saying "Wow! How did/could you remember/know that proverb?"

Comment: Mine lead to the first. :). My intentions are the same as you mentioned now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither is wrong. They just mean different things.

“What memory!” refers to "memory" as a general concept.

If someone remembered things very well, you might say "What memory!" to mean "What (good) memory (you have)!"

“What a memory!” refers to a specific memory.

If someone told you a story, you might say "What a memory!" to mean "What a (good) memory (you have just talked about)!"

Edit: As noted in the comments, you could say "What a memory!" to refer to the general concept of memory as well. The example would be similar to "What a (good) memory (you have)!"

Comment: "What a memory!" does not necessarily refer to remembering a pleasant incident in the past.

Comment: That's true. I was just trying to give examples of use. 
"What a memory!" could also refer to the general "memory" as in the first example.

Comment: If that is the case, then what would be the difference between the two?

Comment: You couldn't use "What memory!" to talk about a specific memory.

Comment: Okay. I am happy with that I guess.

Comment: Could you suggest the write one for the context that I added to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22050/discussion-between-delia-and-gogreen).

Comment: I'm not happy that the non-count usage of _memory_ is ever used in this way ('What memory you have.') I think it would always be 'What a memory [you have].' You'd never say 'What mind she has.'

Comment: I don't mean to criticize but: *"If someone remembered things very well, you might say "What memory!"* No. Without the article "a" that phrase sounds weird within *that* context. It's "I have **a good memory for** numbers" NOT "I have good memory for numbers"

Comment: I agree entirely with @Edwin here. “What memory!” as an exclamation is just not used in any context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's not a good comparison, because "mind" is always countable (at least in the relevant sense), but "memory" can be uncountable. If someone displays a feat of strength, one might exclaim "What strength!". Simlarly if someone demonstrates a feat of memory, "What memory!" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @psmears I can't find a dictionary licensing 'What memory!' (ie the mass noun usage for 'power/s of recollect'). As Mari-Lou says, 'I have good memory for numbers' is unacceptable. On Google Ngrams, 'What memories they have' gives a graph, but 'What memory they have', 'What good memory they have' and 'What poor memory they have' flatline. Are you going to try to back up your claim? Janus makes the diametrically opposite claim. I've given at least some evidence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure exactly what you're after. The first [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/memory) I tried gives "C or U" (i.e. countable or uncountable/mass) for the definition "the ability to remember information, experiences, and people" - is that what you're looking for? If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: No, examples licensing the particular usages. They go on to give _After the accident he suffered from loss of memory/memory loss.
She has **an** excellent memory for names (= she can remember names easily)._ NOT  _She has excellent memory for names_, notice. Dictionaries are often misleading by being elliptical. Longman gives: have a good/excellent memory
have a bad/poor/terrible etc memory
have a memory like a sieve (=have a very bad memory)
have a long memory (=be able to remember things for a long time)
have a short memory // If [my] memory serves me right [can be used count or non-count].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: ... and isn't the last of those ("if memory serves me right") not an example of exactly what we're looking for? Particularly as it's immediately followed with "[can be used count or non-count"?

Comment: The qualification in square brackets is mine, for that particular expression only. That's the usual usage of square brackets. The implication is _not_ that either usage is freely available.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There is more than one use for square brackets, especially in dictionaries - note the one I pointed to uses them to annotate countability! Even without that - I genuinely don't understand why the last example doesn't satisfy you. Not trying to be difficult - but to me it seems "obvious" that "What memory!" is acceptable; clearly it is not so to you, OK, but it does mean I don't understand your objection! For comparison: to me, "What a memory!" vs "What memory!" is parallel to "What an imagination!" vs "What imagination!". Are both acceptable to you? If not, can you say why not?

Comment: 'What imagination!' and 'What an imagination!' present me with no problems. 'What a mind' is fine, but 'What mind!' is unacceptable (I'd say, to everyone). This is true even though 'mind' can on occasion be used in a non-count role ('It's a case of mind over matter'). Similarly with 'What a farce!', 'What a mess!' & 'What a war!' Both Janus and I agree that 'What memory!' is unacceptable; no dictionaries can be comprehensive enough to pronounce on the acceptability of each individual case, and, as here, can be too broad-brush. Sometimes, both versions _are_ acceptable (What [a] cheek!)

Comment: _Conscience_ is another word with tricky count / non-count usages. 'He has a guilty conscience' but *'He has guilty conscience'. *'Since the principle of a conscience is apparently a moral principle, it is presumably one on which we should act in appropriate circumstances.' but [internet] 'Since the principle of conscience is apparently a moral principle, it is presumably one on which we should act in appropriate circumstances.'

Comment: I didn't mean to start a debate guys. :/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks. It does still seem to me, though, that there is a difference between something being *unacceptable*, versus *unusual* (in the sense that it's not *absolutely* unacceptable, but hard to imagine circumstances where it would fit well). In the "what memory" case I grant that there are almost always more idiomatic alternatives, but I'm not convinced it is unacceptable *per se*. Trying to come up with a case where it's more acceptable, consider: (1) "Imagination is an important quality for artists. What imagination they have... what imagination!", then correspondingly...

Comment: (2) "Memory is an important quality for taxi drivers. What memory they have... what memory!" I'd contend that, while (2) is not the most elegant sentence in the language, it's not improved by replacing "memory" with "a memory" (which makes it sound as if the taxi drivers possess some sort of communal hive-mind) or with "memories" (which suggests they have interesting recollections of past passengers). It's certainly not unacceptable to me, though I guess this discussion shows the concept of "acceptability" is fuzzy at the edges, even among native speakers!

Comment: There have been many attempts to give acceptable readings of Chomsky's   'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.' One wonders why. _psmears is trying to prove 'What memory!' acceptable'_ obviously 'works'. But here OP adds _Context:

Someone recollects a proverb that he/she read somewhere. I am intending to praise this person. So which usage would be apt for the situation?_ Admittedly, it's hard to decide on which degree of 'unacceptability' / 'inappropriateness' (Svartvik's classification of non-grammaticality) applies here. Perhaps 1% acceptable. _This answer is misleading and unhelpful._

Answer (score 2):

The second is correct if referring to a singular instance of memory. If you were impressed by someone's ability to remember, that would be singular and again the second form is correct there.

If you were referring to many memories rather than a specific memory, you would use the plural "what memories!" (for example, when referring to an entire year "1986, ah the memories!").

The first version ("what memory!") could be taken as sarcasm, even with the exclamation mark. It could be used colloquially if someone referred to a memory you had of something, and you wanted to convey that you didn't actually remember the occasion that they were referring to.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, because it's correct, and I liked the interpretation for "What memory!"

Comment: But this ("what memory!"  taken as sarcasm) doesn't fit in with OP's intended sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the OP edited his question after this answer was posted. The OP originally asked only if "What memory!" was incorrect.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I had only added extra content to my question. The context that you had asked for. I appreciate all answers but unlike mentioned here, I had no intention of sarcasm. I find the first answer to be most fitting.

Answer (score 2):

The term *[memory](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/memory)* is both a countable and uncountable/mass noun.
When we speak about one's capacity or ability to retain information we can speak about having
**a "memory" for** something. The OD provides these examples of usage

> I’ve **a** great memory for faces
>   She still has **a** great memory for all the old Irish songs and poems.

We can have one or more memories of the past

> (*sing*) What happened during that week was just **a** bad memory in the past
>   (*pl*) I have no recollection of my past memories, except periodic flashbacks of my previous life.

The noun *memory* is singular when it means "mind". It is not generally used in the plural.

> (*sing*) Williams searched his *memory*, trying to remember what he did in this situation eleven years ago.

It is a **mass** noun when we are remembering or honouring the life of a dead person.

> A candlelit vigil took place in Huyton last night, one week after the alleged assault, to honour the dead teenager's memory

and when we speaking about a certain length of time

> After one of the most hectic holiday seasons **in recent memory**, many of us have settled in for equally hectic work schedules.

---

If we were speaking about our childhood, and we retold delightful stories about our past the listener might say

> 1. What lovely memories you have!

Which could be shortened to

> 2. What memories!

If we were speaking about a single incident that happened over fifty years ago, when we were three years old. The listener would exclaim in admiration.

> 3. What **a** great memory you have!
> 4. What **a** memory!

The phrase might refer to the actual recollection or to the speaker's capacity to remember something that happened so long ago.

Comment: I don’t think _memory_ is a mass noun as such when remembering or honouring someone who’s died—it’s just only used in the definite. You can still pluralise it, though: “We are gathered here to honour the memories of all those brave soldiers who died fighting for their country”. It’s closer to a mass noun in certain fixed prepositional phrases: reciting _from memory_, doing something _in memory of_ someone, and indeed _in recent memory_. Apart from that niggle, this is the only answer that correctly answers the question, hence my upvote.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thank you. I think though in  the citation taken from OD you would never use the plural form e.g. "to honour Churchill's memory" and not "memories" which would mean something quite different. But your example does illustrate how the plural might be used because you are speaking about "the memory" of each soldier.

Comment: Exactly—if there are many people, there can be many memories to honour. “We honour his memory” ~ “We honour their memory” [if seen as a group] ~ “We honour their memories” [if seen as individuals].